# Print possible strings created from a Number

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, combinatorics

Given a 10 digit Telephone Number, we have to print all possible strings created from that. The mapping of the numbers is the one as exactly on a phone's keypad.

i.e. for 1,0-> No Letter
      for 2-> A,B,C

So for example, 1230
ADG
BDG
CDG
AEG....

Whats the best solution in c/c++ to this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "programming style" in this context?

Comment: homework? if it does tag it please

Comment: This is not any homework. I am asking for a good solution to this problem...

Comment: This is a pretty common CPSC type question, you should have no trouble finding a wide range of implementations with a quick google search. Now if you want constructive advice on your attempt, please post that and we can help.

Comment: I have no idea on how to solve this. I am preparing for a job interview. Any light thrown would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you can't even articulate *how* you would solve that problem, you're in no position to worry about coding style. Good luck with that interview.

Comment: @Ari: your hint is in this post's tags. Go google them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code Golf: Phone Number to Words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969696/code-golf-phone-number-to-words)

Answer (score 2):

I think a recursive solution would be good for this one. So something like:

```
def PossibleWords(numberInput, cumulative, results):
    if len(numberInput) == 0:
        results.append(cumulative)
    else:
        num = numberInput[0]
        rest = numberInput[1:]
        possibilities = mapping[num]
        if len(possibilities) == 0:
            PossibleWords(rest, cumulative, results)
        else:
            for p in possibilities:
                PossibleWords(rest, cumulative + p, results)

result = []
PossibleWords('1243543', '', result)
```

Comment: Did you mean to pass results as the 3rd parameter of the recursive call to PossibleWords()?

Comment: Can you give an example in c or c++?

Comment: You only asked for a good solution to this problem. Why would you need a specific example in c or c++ if this isn't a homework question? Python is as close as you'll get to pseudocode. I recommend working it out yourself.

Comment: @Suppressingfire - Thanks! Yeah, there were a few problems with the initial code. I've tested it now, and all seems to work well.

Comment: @Ari: so are you planning on faking your way through a job with SO too?

Comment: No. I am expecting similar type of questions and i just wanted a good example in c or c++ on how to solve this type of question. i know i can make mappings like:

one[] = "";
two[] = "A,B,C";
three[] = "D,E,F";

i am confused what to do after mapping when i am parsing the phone number.

Believe me pals....i am not kidding around here......its a long time i am not in touch with c/c++ coding.

Answer (score 1):

No need to go recursive. Here is an example of an iterative approach to start with. It prints out all the possibilities, but you may not entirely like its behaviour. The catch is left for the reader to discover ;-)

```
string tab[10]={"","","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"};
string s="1201075384"; //input string

for(int mask=0;mask<1048576;mask++)//4^10, trying all the posibilities
{
  int m=mask;
  string cur="";
  for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++,m/=4)  
    if (m%4<tab[s[i]-'0'].size())
      cur+=tab[s[i]-'0'][m%4];
  cout<<cur<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A C++ version of Smashery's python solution:

```
string getMapping(int num){
    assert(num>=2 && num<=9);

    switch(num){
        case 2:
            return "ABC";
        case 3:
            return "DEF";
        case 4:
            return "GHI";
        case 5:
            return "JKL";
        case 6:
            return "MNO";
        case 7:
            return "PRS";
        case 8:
            return "TUV";
        case 9:
            return "WXY";
        default:
            return " ";
    }
}


// Recursive function
void generateWords(string input, string cumulative, vector<string> &result){

    if(input.length() == 0){
        result.push_back(cumulative);
    }
    else{
        int num = input.at(0) - '0';
        string rest = input.substr(1, input.length()-1);
        string mapString = getMapping(num);
        if(mapString.compare(" ") != 0){
            for(int i=0; i<mapString.length(); i++){
                generateWords(rest, cumulative+mapString.at(i), result);
            }
        }
        else{
            assert(1==0);
        }
    }
}


void process(){

    generateWords("4734", "", words);

}
```