# Mathematica: How to obtain data points plotted by plot command?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When plotting a function using Plot, I would like to obtain the set of data points plotted by the Plot command.

For instance, how can I obtain the list of points {t,f} Plot uses in the following simple example?

```
f = Sin[t]
Plot[f, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I tried using a method of appending values to a list, shown on page 4 of Numerical1.ps (Numerical Computation in Mathematica) by Jerry B. Keiper, http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4687/ as follows:

```
f = Sin[t]
flist={}
Plot[f, {t, 0, 10}, AppendTo[flist,{t,f[t]}]]
```

but generate error messages no matter what I try.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error messages are quite understandable. The use of `AppendTo` as a third argument of `Plot` is not a supported syntax. I just examined the 19 year old paper (time flies if you're having fun) you were referring to and it uses the compound syntax similar to the one I used below.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate?  I know it has been asked before, and I thought I saw it on StackOverflow, but now I cannot find it.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard. Perhaps  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726317/getting-coordinates-of-manually-drawn-points)?

Comment: @TomD I don't believe that is what I am recalling.  It was probably a MathGroup message.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
f = Sin[t];
plot = Plot[f, {t, 0, 10}]
```

One way to extract points is as follows:

```
points = Cases[
   Cases[InputForm[plot], Line[___], 
    Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity];
```

ListPlot to 'take a look'

```
ListPlot[points]
```

giving the following:

[image]

**EDIT**
Brett Champion has pointed out that `InputForm` is superfluous.

```
ListPlot@Cases[
  Cases[plot, Line[___], Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, 
  Infinity]
```

will work.

It is also possible to paste in the plot graphic, and this is sometimes useful.  If,say, I create a ListPlot of external data and then mislay the data file (so that I only have access to the generated graphic), I may regenerate the data by selecting the graphic cell bracket,copy and paste:

```
ListPlot@Transpose[{Range[10], 4 Range[10]}]

points = Cases[
  Cases[** Paste_Grphic _Here **, Point[___], 
   Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity]
```

**Edit 2**.

I should also have cross-referenced and acknowledged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245946/vertexcoordinate-rules-and-vertexlist-from-graphplot-graphic/4250069#4250069) very nice answer by Yaroslav Bulatov.

**Edit 3**

Brett Champion has not only pointed out that `FullForm` is superfluous, but that in cases where a `GraphicsComplex` is generated, applying `Normal` will convert the complex into primitives. This can be very useful.

For example:

```
lp = ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[10], Range[10]}], 
  Filling -> Bottom]; Cases[
 Cases[Normal@lp, Point[___], 
  Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity]
```

gives (correctly)

> {{1., 1.}, {2., 2.}, {3., 3.}, {4., 4.}, {5., 5.}, {6., 6.}, {7., 
>     7.}, {8., 8.}, {9., 9.}, {10., 10.}}

Thanks to Brett Champion.

Finally, a neater way of using the general approach given in this answer, which I found [here](http://mathgis.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-extract-points-from-plot.html)

The OP problem, in terms of a ListPlot, may be obtained as follows:

```
ListPlot@Cases[g, x_Line :> First@x, Infinity]
```

**Edit 4**

Even simpler

```
ListPlot@Cases[plot, Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity]
```

or

```
ListPlot@Cases[** Paste_Grphic _Here **, Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity]
```

or

```
ListPlot@plot[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]]
```

This evaluates to `True`

```
plot[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]] == Cases[plot, Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity]
```

Comment: `InputForm` is unnecessary, but you might replace it with `Normal` if you don't have control over where the plot is coming from.  If you add a Filling option, for example, the plot will contain `GraphicsComcplex` and the points will just be integer references to the global set of points.

Comment: @Brett Champion  Thanks!  I never realized that `InputForm` was superfluous.  I have edited accordingly.  I usually 'take a look' before data extraction. ( Usually a strategy then suggests itself.)  Can you post an example where GraphicsComplex will give integer refs? `f = Sin[t];
plotfill = Plot[f, {t, 0, 10}, Filling -> Axis];
ListPlot@Cases[
  Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[___], 
   Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity]` will work, for example. Thanks for your comment.  I use this approach quite a bit.

Comment: `ListPlot[{1, 2}, Filling -> Bottom]` contains the following GraphicsComplex: `GraphicsComplex[{{1., 1.}, {2., 2.}, {1., 0.}, {2., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {2., 2.}}, 
  {{{}, {}, {}, {}, {Directive[{Opacity[0.2], Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]}], Line[{3, 1}], 
     Line[{4, 2}]}}, {{}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Point[{5, 6}]}, {}}}]`.  The `Line[{4,2}]` means that we're drawing a line from the fourth point (`{2., 0.}`) to the second point (`{2., 2.}`).

Comment: @Brett Champion Once again, many thanks!  I'm afraid I initially missed you point about `Normal` and how (as I learn from the Help on GraphicsComplex) it may be used to split a `GraphicsComplex` into primitives.  `Cases[Cases[Normal@ListPlot[{1, 2}, Filling -> Bottom], Point[___], 
  Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity]` will abstract the (two) data points from the example you give. Leaving it out, or substituting `FullForm` will not work. This is good to know, and (again) thanks!

Answer (score 14):

One way is to use `EvaluationMonitor` option with `Reap` and `Sow`, for example

```
In[4]:= 
(points = Reap[Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,4Pi},EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[{x,Sin[x]}]]][[2,1]])//Short

Out[4]//Short= {{2.56457*10^-7,2.56457*10^-7},<<699>>,{12.5621,-<<21>>}}
```

Comment: And for any situation where EvaluationMonitor is not available you can make use of a compound statement, e.g. as in: `{plot, {points}} = Reap[Plot[Sow[x]; Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]];` Note that in this particular case the first two points should be dropped as they are not part of the numerical evaluation loop.

Comment: @Sjoerd  I second this. I actually used this method in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667323/mathematica-envelope-detection-data-smoothing/4668972#4668972 . But, since I assumed that the OP saw that answer, and since `EvaluationMonitor` allows to avoid this step and is perhaps generally "cleaner" when available, I used it here.

Comment: `EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[{x,Sin[x]}]` requires additional evaluation of the objective function at every point. See my answer for much more efficient solution (similar to  @Sjoerd's but different).

Comment: you can do `Plot[y=Sin[x]...EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[{x,y}]]`

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the methods mentioned in [Leonid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364088/mathematica-how-to-obtain-data-points-plotted-by-plot-command/5364257#5364257) and my follow-up comment, to track plotting progress of slow functions in real time to see what's happening you could do the following (using the example of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5357419/615464) recent question):

```
(* CPU intensive function *)
LogNormalStableCDF[{alpha_, beta_, gamma_, sigma_, delta_}, x_] :=
 Block[{u},
  NExpectation[
   CDF[StableDistribution[alpha, beta, gamma, sigma], (x - delta)/u], 
   u \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[Log[gamma], sigma]]]

(* real time tracking of plot process *)
res = {};
ListLinePlot[res // Sort, Mesh -> All] // Dynamic

Plot[(AppendTo[res, {x, #}]; #) &@
  LogNormalStableCDF[{1.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1}, x], {x, -4, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

etc.

Comment: IMHO this is a very nice way to monitor plot progress. kudos.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very efficient way to get all the data points:

```
{plot, {points}} = Reap @ Plot[Last@Sow@{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could make the part inside Plot and the assignment a little cleaner, at the expense of a more elaborate Reap syntax: `{plot, points} = Reap[ Plot[Sow[Sin@x, x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}], _, {#, #2[[1]]} &]`

Comment: @Mr. It is very instructive example of usage of the third argument of `Reap`, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer of Sjoerd C. de Vries, I've now written the following code which automates a plot preview (tested on Mathematica 8):

```
pairs[x_, y_List]:={x, #}& /@ y
pairs[x_, y_]:={x, y}
condtranspose[x:{{_List ..}..}]:=Transpose @ x
condtranspose[x_]:=x
Protect[SaveData]
MonitorPlot[f_, range_, options: OptionsPattern[]]:=
  Module[{data={}, plot},
    Module[{tmp=#},
      If[FilterRules[{options},SaveData]!={},
        ReleaseHold[Hold[SaveData=condtranspose[data]]/.FilterRules[{options},SaveData]];tmp]]&@
    Monitor[Plot[(data=Union[data, {pairs[range[[1]], #]}]; #)& @ f, range,
                 Evaluate[FilterRules[{options}, Options[Plot]]]],
      plot=ListLinePlot[condtranspose[data], Mesh->All,
      FilterRules[{options}, Options[ListLinePlot]]];
      Show[plot, Module[{yrange=Options[plot, PlotRange][[1,2,2]]},
        Graphics[Line[{{range[[1]], yrange[[1]]}, {range[[1]], yrange[[2]]}}]]]]]]
SetAttributes[MonitorPlot, HoldAll]
```

In addition to showing the progress of the plot, it also marks the x position where it currently calculates.

The main problem is that for multiple plots, Mathematica applies the same plot style for all curves in the final plot (interestingly, it doesn't on the temporary plots).

To get the data produced into the variable `dest`, use the option `SaveData:>dest`

Comment: Very nice! +1. An example of use: `MonitorPlot[Pause[.08];Sin[x],{x,0,Pi},PlotRange->{{0,Pi},Full}]`.

Comment: Related: "[How Plot\[\] works in mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7204383/590388)."

Answer (score 3):

Just another way, possibly implementation dependent:

```
ListPlot@Flatten[
            Plot[Tan@t, {t, 0, 10}] /. Graphics[{{___, {_, y__}}}, ___] -> {y} /. Line -> List
         , 2]
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to do a rewrite of your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969696/ -- is that OK, or should I post a separate answer?

Comment: @Mr. The usual procedure for code golf questions is to edit the existing answer if your mod is a minor update using the same method, or adding a new one if you propose a different approach. Feel free to decide on that basis.

Answer (score 3):

Just look into structure of plot (for different type of plots there would be a little bit different structure) and use something like that:

```
plt = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];
lstpoint = plt[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]];
```